# read some column in csv data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have data csv

```
word,centroid
she,1
great,0
good,3
mother,2
father,2
After,4
before,4
.....
```

I just want to see the `centroid`

my code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/hasil_cluster.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") 
print(df['centroid'])
```

and error:

```
KeyError: 'centroid'
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: ['word', 'centroid;']

Comment: problem is `;` after `centroid`

Comment: how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `;` after `centroid`:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['word', 'centroid;']
```

You can remove all `;` before and after column names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip(';')
```

Or use `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'centroid;':'centroid'})
```

Or reassign columns names:

```
df.columns = ['word', 'centroid']
```

Comment: Why did it happen?

Comment: @MuhammadRusli - Not idea, data related problem - maybe typo, bug in some system,...